# Apache 403 Forbidden error when configuring a directory outside of root directory

Tags: apache, redhat, selinux

I'm trying to config my server to use a directory /home/imagenesDBD and I Can't get it work, I have googled a lot, and made every sample I found, but nothing is working, i Just add the following to the httpd.conf file

```
Alias "/imagenesDBD" "/home/imagenesDBD"
<Directory "/home/imagenesDBD">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

The directory has 0777 permission setting

[image: Permission of execution]

The context of the Directories are

[image: context directories]

I was Expecting to get this URL Working http://mydomain/imagenesDBD

and got the following error

403 - You don't have permission to access /imagenesDBD/ on this server.

[image: You don't have permission to access /imagenesDBD/ on this server.]

thanks for your help

Comment: If SELINUX is enabled, you have to change the context of `/home/imagenesDBD` to match the context of `/var/www/html`. SELINUX prevents `httpd` from reading directories with wrong context. `ls -Z /home/imagenesDBD` and `ls -Z /var/www/html` will show the contexts of these 2 directories. Please post the contexts in your question.

Comment: It should be `ls -Zd /var/www/html` and `ls -Zd /home/imagenesDBD`. Please post the result. Post the result of `getenforce` as well.

Comment: I have edited the question with the context. thanks for your help, what should i do now?

Comment: The type context of `/home/imagenesDBD` is `home_root_t`. SELINUX will only allow type context `httpd_sys_content_t`. You should change the type context and it can be done by running `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/imagenesDBD`.

Comment: You're a Genius man, how did you know it and where could I read about it?

Comment: `SELINUX` was initially released in January 1, 1998. It's been there for 18 years but everyone seems to be ignoring it. Here's the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type context of `/home/imagenesDBD` is `home_root_t`.

SELINUX will only allow type context `httpd_sys_content_t`.

You should change the type of security context and it can be done by running

```
$ sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/imagenesDBD
```

Here you can found `chcon` manual [chcon](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chcon1.html)

Comment: It took me way too long to find this answer thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Every directory from document root up to server root needs to be executable in order for apache to traverse.

Make home and root executable

```
sudo chmod +x /
sudo chmod +x /home
```

Also make sure you actually have an index page or `Options Indexes`

Comment: I have done the changes and the error continues, i'm going to edit the question with it, thanks for your help

Comment: @OscarDavid you added the options indexes, or have you tried going to the specific page, such as http://example.com/imagenesDBD/index.php

Comment: I create a file with hello world and got the same error:  You don't have permission to access /imagenesDBD/index.php